# How to filter for HTML nodes that are visible on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm currently working on a chrome extension that will allow me to extract font files from fonts on a webpage.

However, I'm noticing that for some websites (like [Ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/)) certain fonts are applied to elements that are **not** visible on the page.

For example if I check `window.getComputedStyle().fontFamily` for the `<title>` tag, I see the font as `Times`.

Since this is the title tag, there are no elements with that font actually being displayed on the page. Is it possible to only filter for nodes that have text that is visible on the webpage?

Note: The nodes don't have to be only visible in the viewport. I' like to pickup nodes that are anywhere on the page.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you attempt to access the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Your best best might be to use **querySelectorAll** to get all child elements within `body`. Wrapping the querySelectorAll with `[].slide.call` to cleanly turn the NodeList into an Array, allowing for us to filter with `[].filter`.

```
var childNodes = [].slice.call(document.body.querySelectorAll("*"));
var visibleNodes = childNodes.filter(node => node.offsetWidth > 0 && node.offsetHeight > 0);
```

For most cases, checking for visibility is of an element is preferred using an elements [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) and [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) attributes as compared to jQuery’s naive method of the `:visible` selector where it just checks if a CSS attribute `display: none` exists.

If you also want a list of all computed font families for visible elements you can use the same `window.getComputedStyle` to get the used value and filter out all empty or null values with double bangs `!!`.

```
var fontFamilies = visibleNodes.map(node => window.getComputedStyle(node).fontFamily).filter(ff => !!ff));
```

Using a unique List of font families using the `…` spread operator in-combo with `Set`.

```
var uniqueFamilies = […new Set(fontFamilies)];
```